# WPF Full width DataGridColumn on DataGrid's width

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a **WPF** `Window` with a `DataGrid` inside a `Grid` like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock FontSize="20">Some header with some pretty longish text</TextBlock>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Height="200">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'd like the `DataGrid`'s width to be at least the width of the `TextBlock`, which in this case is, because of the `Grid`'s `ColumnDefinition`'s width set to `Auto`.

But somehow, the width of the `DataGrid`'s `Column` is at a minimum (and can't even be resized), while I expect it's width to be filled. Currently it looks like this:
[image]

Note that the window has to be a `ToolWindow` and it's `SizeToContent` set to `WidthAndHeight`.

Comment: `Width="*"` would be invalid for `DataGrid`'s column. That seems to work only for `Grid`'s column. Why do you want that?

Comment: What? I'm **not** using `Width="*"` on the `DataGrid`, I'm using it on the `DataGridColumn`. And why? Because I want the width of the `DataGridColumn` to be as wide as it's container.

Comment: Sorry, I tried my code in Kaxaml and it did not behave exactly as what I tried in VS. One word to say: ***Bad design*** about the `DataGrid`. We are  almost impossible to do this simple thing using pure XAML. I bet there is some way using code (such as a Converter) but I would not try to solve this problem using that way. I'll try tweaking more with pure XAML, if I find something I'll re-add my answer. But for now I'm almost sure that it's very hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works at runtime but does not (always) seem to show up right in the designer.

1. Surround the DataGrid in some wrapper (another Grid is fine)
2. Bind the DataGrid's with to the ActualWidth of the wrapper either using relative source or element name:

   a. `Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=WrapperGrid}"`

   b. `Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid}}"`

If you don't have the `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` option it does **not** show up right in the designer:

[image]

But, no matter what after you run it, the width is proper:

With `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`:

[image]

Without `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`:

[image]

Full code below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition
                Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock
            x:Name="Tb1"
            FontSize="20">Some header with some pretty longish text</TextBlock>

        <Grid
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0">

            <DataGrid
                Grid.Row="1"
                Height="200"
                Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid}}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Column1"
                        Width="*" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Or set Width to * instead of Auto.

Comment: If I get rid of the `ColumnDefinition` (basically being a `Width="*"`, since that is the default value of a `Grid`'s column or row definition), then the width of the window will be maximized! This is not a desired effect, and I rather not set any width or maxwidth on the window.

Answer (score 2):

The only work around that i could come up with is to to set the column's width manually from code behind when the `DataGrid` is loaded using the `DataGrid`'s [`ActualWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.actualwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Height="200" x:Name="MyDg" Loaded="MyDg_OnLoaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MyDgtc" Header="Column1"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Handler:

```
  private void MyDg_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
        MyDgtc.Width = MyDg.ActualWidth;
  }
```

I am also interested why is this behavior occurring, i will update my answer once i find something.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

- (star) take up any available remaining space

> Fixed :   Fixed size of logical units (1/96 inch)

Auto :  *Takes as much space as needed by the contained control*

> > Star (*) :    Takes as much space as available (after filling all auto and fixed sized columns), proportionally divided over all star-sized columns. So 3*/5* means the same as 30*/50*. Remember that star-sizing does not work if the grid size is calculated based on its content.

Comment: Please add a description

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBlock Name="Fred" FontSize="20" Text="Some header with pretty longish test" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Height="200" MinColumnWidth="{Binding ElementName=Fred, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Use a databinding to get the actualwidth of the textblock (I called it 'fred') and use that to set the mincolumnwidth of the datagrid.

Comment: With this binding you are setting `DataGrid` width to be exact of `TextBlock` (try very short text). Rather set [`MinWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minwidth(v=vs.110).aspx), this will let `DataGrid` to stretch If window width is bigger than `TextBlock`.

Comment: I made some adjustments, using mincolumnwidth ended up being better. I also had to set the horizontalalignment on the textblock to make it work better.

Answer (score 0):

first sorry for my english

Here, what you need.

your problem is in the definition of the space left for the lines to occupy, as others have already informed you if leaving as "auto" it will occupy the necessary width to box your contents and nothing else, if you leave * it will occupy all remaining space available

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Your window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"  
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" >
    <Grid>
        <!-- not necessary but you can set it -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- your rows -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- first row -->
        <Grid Row="0">
             <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Some header with some pretty longish text"/>
        </Grid>

        <!-- second line, your datagrid, I have changed to fit all available space -->
        <Grid Row="1">
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Width="*" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```